# HTTP_GET not clarified in scope

Tags: esp32, web-server, http

I'm trying to do an async webserver with access point using an ESP32.

It's a little bit of a mix between [This tutorial](https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/01/07/esp32-arduino-http-server-over-soft-ap/) for AP and async and [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-async-web-server-espasyncwebserver-library/) since it's also with an async webserver and it uses inputs which I desperately need.

The part I don't understand is I included all the necessary libraries and I still got this error. If I copy-paste the code in one block everything is fine. It was never necessary to declare `HTTP_GET` since it should be a variable from a library.

So what's wrong?

These are my errors:

```
    In file included from C:\..\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:467:0,
                     from C:\..\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_497972\sketch\webserver.h:5,
                     from C:\..\Async Webserver ESP32\main\main.ino:3:
    C:\..\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/WebHandlerImpl.h: In constructor 'AsyncCallbackWebHandler::AsyncCallbackWebHandler()':
    C:\..\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/WebHandlerImpl.h:76:49: error: 'HTTP_ANY' was not declared in this scope
         AsyncCallbackWebHandler() : _uri(), _method(HTTP_ANY), _onRequest(NULL), _onUpload(NULL), _onBody(NULL), _isRegex(false) {}
                                                     ^
    In file included from C:\..\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:467:0,
                     from C:\..\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_497972\sketch\webserver.h:5,
                     from C:\..\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_497972\sketch\webserver.cpp:1:
    C:\..\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/WebHandlerImpl.h: In constructor 'AsyncCallbackWebHandler::AsyncCallbackWebHandler()':
    C:\..\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/WebHandlerImpl.h:76:49: error: 'HTTP_ANY' was not declared in this scope
         AsyncCallbackWebHandler() : _uri(), _method(HTTP_ANY), _onRequest(NULL), _onUpload(NULL), _onBody(NULL), _isRegex(false) {}
                                                     ^
    C:\Users\Valentin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_497972\sketch\webserver.cpp: In function 'void setup_server(AsyncWebServer)':
    webserver.cpp:6:18: error: 'HTTP_GET' was not declared in this scope
       server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
                      ^
    Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
     Used: C:\..\Arduino15\packages\firebeetle32\hardware\esp32\0.1.1\libraries\WiFi
     Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
    Using library ESPAsyncWebServer-master at version 1.2.3 in folder: C:\..\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master 
    Using library FS at version 1.0 in folder: C:\..\Arduino15\packages\firebeetle32\hardware\esp32\0.1.1\libraries\FS 
    Using library WiFi at version 1.0 in folder: C:\..\Arduino15\packages\firebeetle32\hardware\esp32\0.1.1\libraries\WiFi 
    Using library AsyncTCP-master at version 1.1.1 in folder: C:\..\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTCP-master 
    exit status 1
    'HTTP_GET' was not declared in this scope
```

I already tried to use the standard Arduino WiFi library which resulted just in more errors so I switched it back.

I split up the code into three pieces for better visibility.

**main.ino**

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "webserver.h"
    
// REPLACE WITH YOUR NETWORK CREDENTIALS
const char* ssid = "blabla";
const char* password = "blabla";
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
    
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(IP);
      
  setup_server(server);
}

void loop() {}
```

**webserver.cpp**

```cpp
#include "webserver.h"
    
void setup_server(AsyncWebServer server) {
  // Send web page with input fields to client
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html);
  });
    
  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
  server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_1;
    }
    // GET input2 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input2=<inputMessage>
    else if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_2;
    }
    // GET input3 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input3=<inputMessage>
    else if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_3;
    }
    else {
      inputMessage = "No message sent";
      inputParam = "none";
    }
    Serial.println(inputMessage);
    request->send(200, "text/html", "HTTP GET request sent to your ESP on input field ("
      + inputParam + ") with value: " + inputMessage +
      "<br><a href=\"/\">Return to Home Page</a>");
    });
    server.onNotFound(notFound);
    server.begin();
  }
    
void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

**webserver.h**

```cpp
#ifndef WEBSERVER_H
#define WEBSERVER_H
    
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"
#include "AsyncTCP.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
    
const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "input1";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "input2";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_3 = "input3";
  
AsyncWebServer server(80);
    
String music_state;
IPAddress IP;
    
String inputMessage;
String inputParam;
    
// HTML web page to handle 3 input fields (input1, input2, input3)
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
  <title>ESP Input Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head><body>
  <form action="/get">
    input1: <input type="text" name="input1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get">
    input2: <input type="text" name="input2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get">
    input3: <input type="text" name="input3">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body></html>)rawliteral";

void setup_server(AsyncWebServer server);
    
void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request);
    
#endif
```

Thanks for the input, I will check back tomorrow and answer all questions and test every suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Macro Conflict

You have two basic problems here.  The more significant one is that your use of SERVER_H in your include guard:

```cpp
#ifndef WEBSERVER_H
#define WEBSERVER_H
```

conflicts with a usage in [ESPAsyncWebServer.h](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/f6fff3f91ebf45b91ca4cff2460d2febd61f1e27/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h#L60):

```cpp
#ifndef WEBSERVER_H
typedef enum {
  HTTP_GET     = 0b00000001,
  HTTP_POST    = 0b00000010,
  HTTP_DELETE  = 0b00000100,
  HTTP_PUT     = 0b00001000,
  HTTP_PATCH   = 0b00010000,
  HTTP_HEAD    = 0b00100000,
  HTTP_OPTIONS = 0b01000000,
  HTTP_ANY     = 0b01111111,
} WebRequestMethod;
#endif
```

and that explains why your `HTTP_GET` etc are not found.  They're not being defined because of your include guard macro.

Changing your code to:

```cpp
#ifndef XENOSHELL_WEBSERVER_H
#define XENOSHELL_WEBSERVER_H
```

or something similar will get you past that problem.

### Multiply Defined Variables

You also have some non-static variables defined in your webserver.h that will also need to be changed somehow.  A simple change just being to make them static:

```cpp
static const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "input1";
static const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "input2";
static const char* PARAM_INPUT_3 = "input3";
```

`IPAddress IP;` is only used in main.ino, and should be moved there as a local `const IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();`  If you leave it in the header you'll get multiple definitions because of that.

`String inputMessage;` and `String inputParam;`   Same problem, only these belong inside your lambda expression in `server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {`

I don't know why your server variable is in the header either.  The simplest thing to do is put it in webserver.cpp instead and don't pass it in to `setup_server`, in other word remove the parameter and use the variable defined in the same file as the function.

---

Having done that your code compiles fine.
Whether or not it works is another question.
I am unable to test that.

Comment: hello @timemage thanks for your very detailed answer. I got the code to compile too, but when i tried to connect to the wifi from the ESP the IP adress is not reachable. The output i get from serial monitor is " dhcps: send_offer>>udp_sendto result 0 ". Do you maybe know what could be the problem?

Comment: As of yet, I don't have an ESP32 board, so I have no way of troubleshooting this.  What you're asking about seems like an entirely new question.  I would say cut down your program to the minimal thing necessary to demonstrate the problem.  Given the message you're quoting, your demo program should not have `#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"` or `#include "AsyncTCP.h"` in it at all.  If you don't find the problem in the course of making the demo, post it as part of a new question.

Comment: Ok still thanks for your answers, right now i settle on the version that works and if i have enough time i will come back to this problem

Comment: Thank you! This is a very helpful answer with expert analysis.